# jack audio application routing

Tags: audio, routes, jack

I am quite new to the jack audio software.

I was wondering, whether it is possible to specific applications to specific outputs.

I know could make a virtual device that I can connect anyway I want. But that only works if I am able to select the virtual device as output device within the application, right?

But not all applications have the option to chose outputs.

So the question is whether I can select an application in jack audio and route it the a device of my choice.

Comment: There's a bit more concrete information here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1153655 but I still haven't seen a complete example of starting a couple of applications, starting and setting up everything needed in jack to route one's output to the other's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to do this is the main reason why Jack exists.  You can connect anything to anything with an external patch bay, you don't need to use the UI of the application.

Examples of graphical patch bays you can use are (my) [Patchage](http://drobilla.net/software/patchage), [Catia](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Catia), and [qjackctl](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/).  You can also use `jack_connect` on the command line.

Comment: but what you are talking about is connecting inputs and outputs and stuff to each opther right? i want to directly connect a specific program/software to an output and not connected/create virtual inputs/outputs

Comment: There are no "virtual" inputs/outputs in Jack, there are only input ports and output ports, and they are all essentially the same.

It sounds like application UIs are confusing you about how Jack works.  I suggest you get one of the above-mentioned patch bays and play with it, and you will see what I mean.